# Fit function to histogram

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions, nonlinear, histograms

I have a list:

```
histx={-56.6335, -57.2327, -57.8607, -57.9682, -57.0061, -57.1872,-56.9209, -56.1284,...};
```

I managed to create the histogram that I wanted to:

[image]

But I have a problem with fitting gaussian to it:

[image]

How list should be defined to get NonlinearModelFit?

Comment: You did not include `histx` in the `NonlinearModelFit`. When posting questions, include a minimal **working** example to include a representative (but not necessarily complete) data set that reproduces the problem that you are experiencing.

Comment: You have a bigger problem and that is using a regression function (`NonlinearModelFit`) to fit a histogram.  If you really have a normal distribution, all you need to do is calculate the mean and standard deviation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is rare than anyone should use a regression function such as `NonlinearModelFit` to estimate the parameters of a histogram (constructed from a random sample from some probability distribution).  If you found that technique in a current class, you should chastise the instructor.

If you have the raw data (rather than just the counts from a histogram which you appear to have), the raw data should be used.  If you know you have a simple random sample from a normal distribution, then the following should be used to obtain the maximum likelihood estimates (mle):

```
SeedRandom[12345];
mle = FindDistributionParameters[histx, NormalDistribution[μ, σ]]
(* {μ -> -47.9086, σ -> 4.03062}  *)

Show[Histogram[histx, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF"],
 Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ] /. mle, x], {x, Min[histx], Max[histx]}]]
```

[image: Histogram and estimated pdf]

Here you get an estimate of the probability density function.  If you really need the vertical scale to be in "counts":

```
binwidth = Differences[HistogramList[histx, "FreedmanDiaconis"][[1]]][[1]];
Show[Histogram[histx, "FreedmanDiaconis"],
 Plot[Length[histx] binwidth PDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ] /. mle, x], {x, Min[histx], Max[histx]}]]
```

[image: Histogram and pdf scaled to give a "count" scale]

And now in the 21st century you should forget about histograms and use nonparametric density estimates especially given that you seem to have a large number of data points (you seem to have something on the order of 12,000 observations?).

```
Show[Histogram[histx, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF"],
  Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]] /. mle, x], {x, Min[histx], Max[histx]}],
  SmoothHistogram[histx, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Histogram, smooth histogram, and normal pdf]

Comment: I have also second question, how to make 90 degree rotated axes labels?

Comment: That would be a new question.

Answer (score 7):

We can use [`FindDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistribution.html.en) as shown below. Before applying that function though, I am going to find the empirical distribution based on the image of the histogram.

##### Get the image points

Crop the image (using Mathematica's interactive image manipulation tools):

[image]

Binarize and edge detect:

```
img2 = EdgeDetect[Binarize[img], 3];
img2
```

[image]

Get the corresponding “white” points:

```
lsPoints = Position[ImageData[img2], 1];
lsPoints2 = Map[{#[[1]], ImageDimensions[img2][[2]] - #[[2]]} &, Reverse /@ lsPoints];
ListPlot[lsPoints2]
```

[image]

Rescale into the histogram image ranges:

```
lsPoints3 = N@Transpose[{Rescale[lsPoints2[[All, 1]], MinMax[lsPoints2[[All, 1]]], {-60, -35}], Rescale[lsPoints2[[All, 2]], MinMax[lsPoints2[[All, 2]]], {0, 610}]}];
Length[lsPoints3]
ListPlot[lsPoints3]

(*2043*)
```

[image]

##### Estimate the number of points

Aggregate by the x-coordinate and find the means of the corresponding y-coordinates:

```
lsPoints4 = Sort@Values[GroupBy[lsPoints3, First, {#[[1, 1]], Mean[#[[All, 2]]]} &]];
Length[lsPoints4]

(*622*)
```

Make an interpolation function:

```
ifunc = Interpolation[lsPoints4, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

[image]

```
Plot[ifunc[x], {x, lsPoints4[[1, 1]], lsPoints4[[-1, 1]]}]
```

[image]

Find the width for each bin:

```
Tally[Differences[lsPoints4[[All, 1]]]]

(*{{0.0402576, 559}, {0.0402576, 62}}*)
```

```
binWidth = Mean[Differences[lsPoints4[[All, 1]]]]

(*0.0402576*)
```

Well, this bin width estimation is more of an artifact of `EdgeDetect`; the histogram bin seems to be a few times wider.

Here is the estimate for total sum of points:

```
nPoints = Ceiling[Total[lsPoints4[[All, 2]]]/4]

(* 31350 *)
```

##### Generate “histogram image estimated” points

Generate the points:

```
lsIntervals = RandomChoice[lsPoints4[[All, 2]] -> lsPoints4[[All, 1]], Floor[nPoints/10]];
ResourceFunction["RecordsSummary"][lsIntervals]
```

[image]

```
lsGeneratedPoints = RandomReal[{#, # + binWidth}] & /@ lsIntervals;
```

```
Histogram[lsGeneratedPoints, {lsPoints4[[1, 1]], lsPoints4[[-1, 1]], 10 binWidth}]
```

[image]

Here is the original image with the histogram (looks close enough):

```
img0
```

[image]

##### Find the distribution

Over the generated points above we apply
[`FindDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistribution.html.en):

```
FindDistribution[lsGeneratedPoints]

(*NormalDistribution[-46.7283, 3.68475]*)
```

##### Verification

```
SeedRandom[6];
Histogram[
 RandomVariate[
  NormalDistribution[-46.728321499135916`, 3.684750636542824`], 10000], 50]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 It is amazing that one can "digitize" the values of a histogram figure and extract the counts and bin boundaries.

Comment: @JimB Thanks! I consider these kind of applications to be not that easy to do in the "competitor" systems, Julia, Python, and R. (I plan to renew my blog posts on  comparisons between them.)